# Inject one line of JavaScript from firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, code-injection, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I am completely new to FF extension creation, and I will be rather specific.

When I run a JS command in, for example, Firefox's built-in sandbox, it works just fine, so I would like to make a FF addon where on click the same JS command would execute. The command basically works in a web page:

javascript:`$('.plus').click();`

I suppose it doesn't have to work like this:

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var tabs = require('tabs');

exports.main = function() {

new Widget({
    id: "user-widget-1",
    label: "My Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function(event) {        
        javascript:$('.plus').click();
    }
});
```

};

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$(.plus)` is jQuery syntax so you probably want to load jQuery as a content script into your widget. And you want to run your code as a content script as well, e.g.:

```js
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

new Widget({
    id: "user-widget-1",
    label: "My Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://example.com/foo.html",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"), data.url("myScript.js")]
});
```

And `data/myScript.js` would be something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.plus').click()
});
```

If you don't want the click to happen when the document loads but rather on a specific event happening in your extension, you might want to look into [communicating with content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html). I also recommend reading a [general overview of content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html).

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help me! But still the extension does not work even on document loading. My code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2HzApdti I have the jquery.min.js and myScript.js of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Page-Mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) to inject content-scripts into a web page, content-script linked in a widget only works in the widget content. Moreover the widget API is deprecated from FF 29, I suggest you to use a [Action button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui#ActionButton) instead.